# Apache Rewrite and Alias combined

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

We have run into an issue where we have an existing Alias, and we would like to add a rewrite rule to catch all variations of case-insensitive spellings, ie:

```
URL:  http://www.example.com/example

Alias  /example  "/var/www/html/web/example"
```

We need a rewrite rule to catch:

```
/ExamPle

/exampLE

/eXAmple
```

etc ...

We cannot seem to get the rewrite & Alias to work together.

Answer (score 2):

In your main configuration:

```
RewriteRule ^/example(?:$|/)(.*) /example/$1 [NC,PT,R]
```

The magic is in the NC (no case) modifier. If you don't want a forward, you can omit the R modifier.
The PT (pass-through) modifier should make it play well with `Alias`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately , this results in  the following error:

Bad Request:
Invalid URI in request GET /example HTTP/1.1

I found how apache internally processes Aliases & Rewrites:

Internal Processing:
  /xyz/oldstuff.html     -> /abc/def/oldstuff.html  (per-server Alias)
  /abc/def/oldstuff.html -> /abc/def/newstuff.html  (per-dir    RewriteRule)
  /abc/def/newstuff.html -> /xyz/newstuff.html      (per-dir    RewriteBase)
  /xyz/newstuff.html     -> /abc/def/newstuff.html  (per-server Alias)


Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Please write what are your current relevant configuration directives.